# Access elements from several tables in IEnumerable in Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor-pages

i want to ask how i can access list contain different elements from several tables in razor views:

```
public IEnumerable Blogs { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    Blogs = await _context.Blog
            .Select(b => new
            {
                b.Id,
                b.Name,                           
                b.Owner.UserName,
            })
            .ToListAsync();

}
```

how i can access it on Razor view ?

when i use the following:

```
@foreach (var b in Model.Blogs)
{
    <div> @b </div>
}
```

i get all the object in line as string !
but i cant use @b.Id for example, i just get Methods (ToString, Equal ...)

how i can access object properties ? ex: @b.Id, @b.Name ...

Thanks

Update :
suppose i want to use this :

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var Blogs = await _context.Blog
            .Select(b => new
            {
                b.Id,
                b.Name,                           
                b.Owner.UserName,
            })
            .ToListAsync();

}
```

how i can access var Blogs by index  ?

Comment: You should probably use a concrete class instead of a anonymous class.  Then your `Blogs` property could be a `List<SomeType>`

Comment: Thanks but as you see i'm using "new" to create new object of custom selected values, so cant use list of type Blog

Comment: I know exactly what you are doing currently, but what you need to do is make a class that has the three properties on it (Id, Name, OwnerName).  And instead of saying `new {}` which is an _anonymous_ class, you would say `new SomeType { }` which is _not_ an anonymous type.  Then your `Blogs` property would be a `List<SomeType>` since you are very clearly calling `ToListAsync()`

Comment: Forget about my query, i need to see the ideas how i can fix it without third class even with new query, see update please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using anonymous objects, you should make a `BlogViewModel` class that has the three properties you want:

```
public class BlogViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
}
```

Then your query and list building logic would be:

```
public List<BlogViewModel> Blogs { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
     Blogs = await _context.Blog
            .Select(b => new BlogViewModel()
            {
                Id = b.Id,
                Name = b.Name,                           
                OwnerName = b.Owner.UserName,
            })
            .ToListAsync();
}
```

Then you can easily access the properties in your loop in the razor

Comment: Thanks man, it seems the best way, but i want to ask, is there anyway to tell that the defined ID is the BLogId i mean i want to avoid adding Data annotation again here as i already added them in each model class ?

Comment: @J.Edmond why do you need to define the ID?  This is just for displaying values in the view model right?  I guess I dont understand why you need the data annotations/attributes

Comment: O.K man but the label ? i mean i want to see : Full Name : <Value>, not FullName so this can be done using DA, no ?

Comment: @J.Edmond your example razor didnt indicate any HTML helpers so I wasnt aware you needed that.  One thing I would suggest is never use your data models in the view, you should always be using ViewModels to transport data to views.  So you might want to rethink where your DA attributes are, but thats a larger effort.

Comment: That's right, i think using ViewModel will be better as we can include what we want only , not the whole model, again thank you, i appreciate your help ! and if you know any way or idea to solve the issue of DA, i mean to declare them once not in each ViewModel, because you know maybe we need to use the Blog  with another object in another page so should we define them again ?, anyway .. your help will be highly appreciated.